# Grails REST Client Plugin - PUT body content

Tags: rest, grails, grails-plugin, httpbuilder

Documentation seems to be lacking on both the plugin side as well as the HTTPBuilder side of things.  I'm trying to submit some json through the put method, but it keeps telling me that put() doesn't like the map I am feeding it.

Does anyone have an example of a PUT using the Grails REST Client plugin?  Here is what I've tried:

```
withHttp(uri: "http://foo/doo/roo") {
        def bodyContent = [
            pano: jsonText
        ]

        def json = put(body: bodyContent)

        if (json.stat == 'ok') {
          wsr.success = true
        }
}
```

Error:

```
No signature of method: com.wbr.pano.PanService.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[body:
    {
      "class":"com.wbr.platform.Pano",
      "errorMessage":"null",
      "imageSize":0,
      "id":26,
      "completed":"2011-03-20 3:50:27.257",
      "downloading":"2011-03-20 3:49:12.269",
      "processing":"2011-03-20 3:49:42.911",
      "uploading":"2011-03-20 3:50:12.107"
    }
  ]]
```

Comment: Can you post the error message/stacktrace you are getting?

Comment: Added error message.  The actual stacktrace is a lot more cryptic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HTTPBuilder](http://svn.codehaus.org/gmod/httpbuilder/trunk/src/main/java/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.java) doesn't have a *put* method.  Try changing **withHttp** to **withRest** so that your statements are executed with the RESTClient.  Also, I think by default the body is encoded as URL encoded, so you might need to specify **requestContentType: groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON** as another parameter to your *put*.

```
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.*

withRest(uri: "http://foo/doo/roo") {
        def bodyContent = [
            pano: jsonText
        ]

        def json = put(body: bodyContent, requestContentType: JSON)

        if (json.status == 200) {
          wsr.success = true
        }
}
```

Comment: I've marked this as correct because it solves the immediate problem.  I'm still having issues with the json data that is going across and grails reading it, even though our functional tests work fine.  But that is another question.